# c# lambda expression with for loop

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, ilnumerics

I'm using this code to build my 3d surface plot in each point, but I have a problem that I need to parametrize my function so t variable will be looped from 0 to T value, but I can't figure it out how can I do it inside the delegate?

edited the first block for more clarity:

```
/*this is code for building 3d surface plot, parameter delegate is counting Z
  value in each (x, y) point.
  x, y are axis variables. t is constant here*/
new ILPlotCube()
{ 
    new ILSurface((x, y) => (float) (1/(x+y+t))
}
```

Resulting pseudocode is something like:

```
float functionValue = 0;
for (double t = 0; t < T; t + deltaT)
{
     /*t is loop parameter here*/
     functionValue += (float) (1/(x+y+t));   
}
return functionValue;
```

Comment: I think you should go to an obfuscated C# code contest... It is three minutes I'm reading the first code block, and I'm still not sure who is the parameter of who

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need an Expression Tree, then it should be:

```
Func<float, float, float> func = (x, y) =>
{
    float functionValue = 0;
    for (double t = 0; t < T; t += deltaT)
    {
        /*t is loop parameter here*/
        functionValue += (float)(1 / (x + y + t));
    }
    return functionValue;
};
```

Note that I had to change the `t + deltaT` adder of the `for`

From there you can

```
new ILSurface(func);
```

This is a `statement lambda`, because it uses `{ ... }` code after the `=>`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397687.aspx `statement lambdas`